# Initializing and passing an ember.js model/object?

Tags: ember.js

```
 export default Ember.Route.extend({
   model: function() {
     return this.store.all('foo');
   }
 });
```

I want to use `store.all` instead of `store.find`, correct, since I don't want to load the contents from HTTP?

Then:
`models/foo`

```
 export default DS.Model.extend({
   firstName: DS.attr('string'),
   lastName: DS.attr('string')
 });
```

Or should I not be using a model, and an Ember Object instead? The docs for initializing an object say to use `App.Foo.Create()`, but AFAIK ES6 modules have gotten rid of the App namespace?

Ultimately I want to define a model, then pass that to a component and edit the values. After which I'll save each instance of that created model until I need to do something with them.

Pseudo code of what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
 var model = {
    key: "value"
 }
 export default model
```

`controller/router:`

```
 import model from 'model'(?)
 this.model = model;
```

`template.hbs:`

```
{{my-component data=model}}
```

Comment: this.store.all returns all the previously loaded records, so that will always give you an empty list, if you haven't pushed anything to the store manually or triggered this.store.find earlier. I don't understand what you want to do. Can you clarify the question?

Comment: Yeah, sorry I'm new to ember.js. I literally just want to define a model, pass that to a component (which I suppose means I have to set it on the route? and not the controller?) and then save changes to the values of the already defined keys (from the model).

Comment: Do you want to load/save changes to a server, so changes are stored when you reload the window? If you dont want to load data from the server, it's easier for you to just return an ember object from your model method: model: function() { return Ember.Object.create({ firstName: 'Iksose'); }